# Unable to fix a warning Duplicate keys detected: '0'. This may cause an update error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js

Vue js throws a warning that says vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Duplicate keys detected: '0'. This may cause an update error.

I tried using the getter and setter in the computed variable and dispatch the value to Vuex store.

Here is the code for the html element

```js
<!-- Displaying Sample TappingPessure input field-->
<v-layout 
wrap row
class="text-xs-left mx-auto pt-2"
style="height:50px;" >

...some code 

<v-flex xs12 md1 sm1 class="ma-0 pa-0"
>
    <v-text-field
    class="myfont1 inputValue"
    name="pressure" 
    id="pressure" 
    required  
    v-model="tappingPressure"
    type="number"
    reverse
    style="max-width:70px;"
        >
    </v-text-field>
</v-flex>
...some code   
</v-layout>
```

here is the code for the computed variable

```js
tappingPressure:{
                get () {
                return this.$store.getters.tappingPressure
                },
                set (value) {
                this.$store.dispatch('setTappingPressure',{data:value})
                }
            },
```

Here is the vuex code for updating the variable

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import '@/firebase/init.js'
import  firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/auth'


import router from "@/router.js"

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
  ...some code
  
  tappingPressure:"",
  
  ...some code
  },
  
  mutations: {
   setTappingPressure(state, payload) {
      state.tappingPressure = payload.data;
    },
    
    ...some code
  },
  
  actions: {
   setTappingPressure({
      commit
    }, payload) {
      commit("setTappingPressure", payload);
    },
    ...some code
    
   },
   
   
   getters: {
   
   tappingPressure(state) {
      return state.tappingPressure;
    },
    
    }
   
});
```

Here is the screenshot of error
[image]

I tried to keep the code outside the stepper and the function that calls Vuetify dialog works nicely. This problem occurs when I call the function from inside a Vuetify stepper. The code is working fine. The vuex is getting updated. The warning messages flood the console .

Somebody please suggest a way out. Thanks in advance

Comment: The error relates to your use of keys. That's the `key` attribute in your template. I don't see a `key` anywhere in your template so it seems we are missing the most important piece.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How do I add a key in the template? could you please elaborate?

Comment: You don't need to add a key. The problem is that you already have a key but it is set to an inappropriate value. Based on the picture it would seem that it is somewhere in the template for `AnadezMain`.

Comment: thank you skirtle. Your reply helped me troubleshoot it myself and I fixed it as you may see from the answer I posted. Thanks again.. Cheers

Comment: Hi skirlte, in fact, the problem was not actually solved with that. I had to spend some more time on it. Finally, I figured it out as you may see from the answer I posted. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem was that there were 2 list rendering in the template....
In both I was using "index" for key binding as shown below

```html
v-for="(compo,index) in compoDataAz" :key="index" 
v-for="(compo, index) in analyteData" :key="index"
```

I changed both  to

```html
v-for="(compo,index) in compoDataAz" :key="'compo'+index"
v-for="(compo, index) in analyteData" :key="'analyte'+index"
```

This fixed the issue. The reason for the warning was that I used "index" as key for both list rendering.  Finally I figured it out thankfully. Just sharing this in case someone else may find it helpful.

Comment: This doesn't look right to me. Just renaming a local variable isn't going to resolve the duplicate key problem. The typical solution would be to use a prefix or suffix to ensure the keys are unique, e.g., `:key="'compo' + index"` for one and `:key="'analyte' + index"` for the other.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I updated my template. Your suggestion is more practical . Thanks again. My code  looks much better now.

Comment: Is that because you've still got `index` renamed to `i`?

Comment: I changed it like you suggested. It's all good now! Thanks :)